# Restkit RKObjectManager requests timeout when downloading a lot of files

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

First off: I'm quite new to RestKit so perhaps this is an easy question to solve.

I am trying to download a lot of files. Currently I use the `getObjectsAtPath:parameters:success:failure:` method of `RKObjectManager` to fetch and map my objects towards restkit.

However, It seems as it starts some downloads prematurely and then timesout when they are in the queue.

The code I am using:

```
- (void)removeResponseAndRequestDescriptors
{
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
    [objectManager.requestDescriptors enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [objectManager removeRequestDescriptor:obj];
    }];

    [objectManager.responseDescriptors enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [objectManager removeResponseDescriptor:obj];
    }];
}
```

.

```
- (void)downloadAudioFileForAudio:(IBAudio *)audio
                           inBook:(IBBook *)book
                  downloadStatus:(void (^)(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead))downloadStatus
                         success:(void (^)(void))success
                         failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure
{
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

    NSString *sessionID = (book.parent ? book.parent.user.session.sessionID : book.user.session.sessionID);
    [objectManager.HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/octet-stream"];
    [objectManager.HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"Session-Id" value:sessionID];

    [objectManager.HTTPClient getPath:[IBProperties downloadAudioEndPointWithIsbn:book.isbn andAnchor:audio.anchor] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSString *folderPath = [self folderPathForBook:book];
        NSString *audioPath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp3", audio.anchor]];
        NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithData:responseObject];

        NSError *fileSystemSaveError;
        [self saveFile:audioData toFilePath:audioPath error:&fileSystemSaveError];
        if (fileSystemSaveError) {
            failure(fileSystemSaveError);
            return;
        }

        // Saving the context asap in case the app dies before it can autosave.
        NSError *coreDataSaveerror;
        [[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore] mainQueueManagedObjectContext] save:&coreDataSaveerror];
        if (coreDataSaveerror) {
            failure(coreDataSaveerror);
            return;
        }

        [audio setFilePath:audioPath];
        success();
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        failure(error);
    }];

    [objectManager.HTTPClient.operationQueue.operations.lastObject setDownloadProgressBlock:downloadStatus];
}
```

.

```
- (void)downloadAudioFiles
{
    for (IBAudio *audio in self.book.bookData.audios) {
        self.numberOfDownloads++;
        [self.downloadPercentagesFiles addObject:[[IBDownloadStatusOfAFile alloc] init]];
        NSInteger arrayIndex = [self.downloadPercentagesFiles count] - 1;

        [[IBDataBackendFetcher sharedBackendFetcher] downloadAudioFileForAudio:audio inBook:self.book downloadStatus:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
            IBDownloadStatusOfAFile *statusOfFile = [self.downloadPercentagesFiles objectAtIndex:arrayIndex];
            statusOfFile.bytesRead = bytesRead;
            statusOfFile.totalBytesRead = totalBytesRead;
            statusOfFile.totalBytesExpectedToRead = totalBytesExpectedToRead;
            [self updateDownloadProgress];
        } success:^{
            [self downloadDidComplete];
        } failure:^(NSError *error) {
            [self.dataProviderDelegate downloadDidFailWithError:error forBookDownloader:self];
        }];
    }
}
```

It seems as it starts all downloads at once, but the actuall download is not started. So the last downloads gets a timeout.

Is there a better way for do this to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the downloads **will** run simultaneously, because you're making all the `getPath:` calls right in a row (they are asynchronous calls). Since each download takes a while to finish, this causes the timeout on the later calls.

If you want each download to occur only after the previous one completes, I would make a method called `getNextAudioFile:` and an iterator class property. Then, in both the `success` and `failure` blocks of `getPath:`, increment your iterator and call `getNextAudioFile:`.

Example code:

```
- (void)downloadAudioFiles
{
   // No for loop
   self.iterator = 0;

   // your call to DownloadAudioFileForAudio: ... for the first audio goes here
}

- (void)downloadAudioFileForAudio:(IBAudio *)audio
                           inBook:(IBBook *)book
                  downloadStatus:(void (^)(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead))downloadStatus
                         success:(void (^)(void))success
                         failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure
{
  // your code ...

  [objectManager.HTTPClient getPath:[IBProperties downloadAudioEndPointWithIsbn:book.isbn andAnchor:audio.anchor] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){

    // your code...

    // increment and get the next file
    self.iterator++;
    [self getNextAudioFile];

  } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    failure(error);

    // increment and get the next file
    self.iterator++;
    [self getNextAudioFile];
  }];
}

- (void)getNextAudioFile
{
  if(self.iterator < [self.book.bookData.audios count]){
    // make your downloadAudioFileForAudio: call for the next audio
  }
}
```

That's the idea at least! Hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Set the maximum number of concurrent operation on the queue to some reasonable value like 5.

```
[objectManager.HTTPClient.operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:5];
```

(before you start any requests)